# Can someone please verify if RedBlack Tree successor is written correctly?

Tags: c++, red-black-tree

```
pair<K,V> *RedBlackTree<K,V,Compare>::successor(K key) {

    Node *found = findNode(key, root);

    Node *p;
    Node *ch;
    Node *x;

    Node *y;
    if(found->right != sentinel)
        return new pair<K,V>(found->right->key, found->right->value);

    y = found->parent;
    /* if it does not have a left child,
    predecessor is its first left ancestor */
    while(y != NULL && found == y->right) {
            found = y;
            y = y->parent;
    }
    return new pair<K,V>(y->key, y->value);



}
```

Comment: Maybe this kind of question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: you may have better luck at Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Holy dynamic allocation, Batman! Returning a pointer to a dynamically allocated `pair` is almost certainly wrong. You probably want to return the `pair` by value. This code doesn't look right: `found->right` isn't always the next node in an inorder traversal because `found->right` may have a left subtree.  I posted an example of how to find the successor [in an answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381867/iterating-over-a-map/3382702#3382702).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is incorrect.  Consider the following tree:

```
   b
  / \
 a   f
    / \
   d   g
  / \
 c   e
```

The in-order successor of `b` is `c`.  Your function thinks the in-order successor is `f`.  To find the in-order successor you have to handle several cases; this example tree has an instance of each case that needs to be handled.  Start at each node and write down the steps that you need to find the in-order successor for each.

If you're interested, you can find an implementation of the algorithm with a full explanation in [an answer I gave to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381867/iterating-over-a-map/3382702#3382702).

---

On an unrelated note, your function should almost certainly be returning a `std::pair` *by value* and you should not be dynamically allocating the `std::pair`.